# power series expansion centered at $z_0 = 0 $ of the function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I've done this but i got very confused.
$$
\begin{gathered}
g(z)=\frac{z}{z^{2}-4 z+13} \\
f(z)=\sum_{n=0} a_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n} \\
f^{(0)}(z)=\frac{z}{z^{2}-4 z+13}, f^{(0)}\left(z_{0}\right)=f^{(0)}(0)=\frac{(0)}{0^{2}-4(0)+13}=0 \\
f^{(1)}(z)=\frac{-z^{2}+13}{\left(z^{2}-4 z+13\right)^{2}}=f^{(1)}(0)=\frac{-0^{2}+13}{\left(0^{2}-4(0)+13\right)^{2}}=\frac{13}{169} \\
f^{(2)}(z)=-\frac{2\left(-z^{3}+39 z-52\right)}{\left(z^{2}-4 z+13\right)^{3}}, f^{(2)}\left(z_{0}\right)=-\frac{2\left(-0^{3}+39(0)-52\right)}{\left(0^{2}-4(0)+13\right)^{3}}=-\frac{52}{2197}
\\f^{3}(z)=-\frac{6\left(z^{4}-78 z^{2}+208 z-39\right)}{\left(z^{2}-4 z+13\right)^{4}},=f^{(3)}(0)=-\frac{6\left(0^{4}-78(0)^{2}+208(0)-39\right)}
{\left(0^{2}-4(0)+13\right)^{4}}=-\frac{39}{28561} \\
\end{gathered}
$$
Is this a correct process or i need to search another form? Can it solve with a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z}$?
Please help :c

Answer (score 1):

If you start writing
$$z^2-4z+13=(z-a)(z-b)\quad \text{with}\quad a=2-3i\quad \text{and}\quad b=2+3i$$

$$\frac z{z^2-4z+13}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{a}{z-a}-\frac{b}{z-b}\right)$$ the successive derivatives are much easier to compute and you will have
$$\frac z{z^2-4z+13}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^{-n}-a^{-n}}{a-b} z^n$$ Using trigonometry you should get the nice
$$\frac z{z^2-4z+13}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty  13^{-n/2} \sin \left(n \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\,z^n$$ all coefficients being rational numbers
$$\left\{\frac{1}{13},\frac{4}{169},\frac{3}{2197},-\frac{40}{28561},-\frac{199}{371293},
   -\frac{276}{4826809},\frac{1483}{62748517},\frac{9520}{815730721},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks, it looks so complex, I lost in the trigonometry :C

Comment: @qw.15125 I hope that you realize how simple are the derivatives.  Using $(a,b)$ which are complex, they write $$c_n=\frac{1}{6} i \left(\left(\frac{2}{13}-\frac{3
   i}{13}\right)^n-\left(\frac{2}{13}+\frac{3 i}{13}\right)^n\right)$$ Now, using de Moivre $$c_n=\frac{1}{3} 13^{-n/2} \sin \left(n \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ and I have all terms

Comment: Thank you so mucho, you really help me a lot

Comment: In this part$\frac z{z^2-4z+13}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^{-n}-a^{-n}}{a-b} z^n$   how does it is a geometric series?